# How to upload a captured image with android device to mysql database using php?

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

I am newbie to android, i am trying to upload an image to mysql server. In my app i have button named upload image when ever user clicks on the button it will open up a camera in android device. I am successfully getting captured image using camera in imageview , i want to save this image in mysql database using php, i am successfully connected to database using php and uploading few fields entered in the edittext but i can not able to upload the image. I googled it but all are showing the uploading image with url. But in my case it is little different look at my code and please help me out.

FormActivity.java

```
public class FormActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static String url_submit_hourly = "http://www.example.com/FacebookApp/submit.php";

EditText tasktitle;

String title;
Button upload, submit;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;
byte[] byteArray;
protected static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
byte[] imgbyte;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.submit_hourly);

    tasktitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etfirst);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new BookSlot().execute();
        }
    });

    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image);
    upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }

    });

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }

}

class BookSlot extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FormActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Hourly..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        title = tasktitle.getText().toString();


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("task_tilte", title));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_submit_hourly,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        FacebookLoginActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

}
```

submit.php

```
<?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['task_tilte'])) {

$title = $_POST['task_tilte'];


// include db connect class
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'/FacebookApp/db_connect.php'); 

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO                       task_table(task_tilte)     VALUES('$title')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I am not getting the idea of how to save the image in imageview to mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the image to a base_64 and then send to PHP to store it in MySQL and when reading it from MySQL you need to decode it